# How to increase my ethernet connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, connection

I have a ZTE Wifi router which I connect using a ethernet cable (USB Cable) onto my pc, on windows the internet speed is fine, but when I boot into my Ubuntu, the internet speed becomes soo slow. How do I fix such a problem?

Comment: What does soo slow mean? Confused by your question, a USB cable is not an Ethernet cable. what are you using? What version of Ubuntu are you using, it matters.

Comment: On Windows, the google speed test is about 10mbps for download speed but on Ubuntu 22.04 it is 0.03mbps. Yes, I am using a USB Cable to connect my router because I don't have a wifi dongle yet.

Comment: but the upload speed goes over 10mbps...